# compiling matrix row assignment

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, compile

I have this relatively simple code, generated with another Mathematica code (this is just an example): (**edit: see below for simpler version**)

```
code = Compile[{{s, _Real, 1}},
Block[{d2s = {{4., -8., 4.}, {4., -8., 4.}, {4., -8., 4.}}.s,
coefficients, MblockCoefficients, Mblocks, M, Mbc, vParts, v},
coefficients = {{{-4.62924, -3.38288, -3.} s^2, {0., 0., 0.}, {1., 
  1., 1.}, {-1., -0.5, 0.} + {-1.54308, -1.12763, -1.} s^3 + 
  d2s}};
vParts = -Last[Transpose[coefficients]];
v = Flatten[vParts];
MblockCoefficients = (Partition[#1, 2 + 1] &) /@Transpose[Most[Transpose[coefficients]]];
Mblocks =Map[Total[MapThread[Dot, {DiagonalMatrix /@ #1, 
{{{1., 0., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0.,0., 1.}}, {{3., -4., 1.}, {1., 0., -1.}, {-1.,4., -3.}}, {{4., -8., 4.}, {4., -8., 4.}, {4., -8.,4.}}}}]] &,
MblockCoefficients, {2}];
M = ArrayFlatten[Mblocks];
v[[{3, 1}]] = {1. - s[[-1]], -0.2 - s[[1]]^3};
Mbc = {{0., 0., 1.}, {0. + 3. s[[1]]^2, 0., 0.}};
M[[{3, 1}]] = Mbc;
Partition[LinearSolve[M, v], 2 + 1]
]];
```

It takes a vector and produces another vector, and as you see it is compiled.

I want to minimise the calls to `MainEvaluate`. There are 4 in this case*, of which I understand 3: `DiagonalMatrix`, `ArrayFlatten` and `LinearSolve` cannot be compiled.

My question is about the 4th one, which comes from the line `M[[{3,1}]] = Mbc`. I thought that maybe this type of assignment on rows of a matrix cannot be compiled, but the following code:

```
code2 = Compile[{{m, _Real, 2}, {v, _Real, 2}}, 
Block[{mnew = m},
mnew[[{3,1}]] = v;
mnew
]];
```

compiles just fine, without any call to `MainEvaluate`.

So what is the problem in the first case, and is there a simple fix?
This is in Mathematica 11.0.0.

**EDIT:**
This I think is a minimal working example of the above code,

```
codeNotWorking=Compile[{{s, _Real, 1}}, Module[{M, Mbc},
M = ArrayFlatten[{{{{1.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 1.`}}, {{0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`}}},   
     {{{0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`}}, {{1.`, 0.`}, {0.`,1.`}}}}];
Mbc = {{0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0. + 3. s[[1]]^2, 0., 0., 0.}};
M[[{3, 1}]] = Mbc;
   ], {{M, _Real, 2}, {Mbc, _Real, 2}}];
```

Again the same line doesn't compile.
Instead if I first evaluate the `ArrayFlatten` and paste the result in the above code, it does compile.
So the problem seems to be that because `ArrayFlatten` doesn't compile, the compiler doesn't know the dimensions of `M`.
But I thought the third argument that I gave should give that information?

*I find these with the code

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
printcode[comp_] := StringReplace[CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[comp],
"MainEvaluate" -> Style["MainEvaluate", Red]]
```

Comment: Maybe you meant to write `M[[3, 1]] = Mbc;` instead of `M[[{3, 1}]] = Mbc;`? That removes the fourth call to `MainEvaluate` for me... But no, that does not make sense.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Exactly `M[[3,1]]` is something else and not what I want. I reduced it further and the issue seems to be that the compiler doesn't know the dimensions of `M`, even when I give them?